# JPA/hibernate is generating the wrong SQL statement

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

My `JpaRepository` is generating the wrong SQL. It only updates shop and not the rest of the entity. After looking closer I noticed the query say `update shop set` nothing about `campaign` entity  in which `shop` is inside.

Inside Campaign there is a shop:

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "SHOP_ID", referencedColumnName = "SHOP_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Shop shop;
```

and inside shop I have a set:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "shop")
private Set<Campaign> campaignSet;
```

The query generated with a `saveAndFlush` -

```
update shop set created_at=?, currency=?, currency_iso_code=?, default_delivery_cost=?, delivery_cost_erp_number=?, description=?, default_language_id=?, modified_at=?, sales_organisation_id=?, code=?, valid_from=?, valid_till=? where shop_id=?
```

I want the whole Campaign to be saved and I honestly do not care about updating the shop because I will never do that when updating a campaign.

Method updating:

```
@Override
@Modifying
@Transactional
public CampaignDto update(CampaignDto campaignDto) throws RequestNotFoundException {
    //TODO: compare objects to see if there is a change

    Campaign campaign = mapper.mapReverse(campaignDto);

    if (campaign.getCampaignId() != null) {
        campaign = campaignRepository.getOne(campaign.getCampaignId());

        if (campaign.getCampaignId() == null) {
            throw new RequestNotFoundException(
                    String.format("Campaign %s is not found", campaign.getKey().toString()));
        }
    }

    Shop shop = shopRepository.getOne(campaignDto.getShopId());

    if (shop.getShopId() > 0 && shop.getShopId() != null) {
        shop.setCode(campaignDto.getShopCode());
        shop.setCurrency(campaignDto.getShopCurrency());
        shop.setCurrencyIsoCode(campaignDto.getShopCurrencyIso());
        shop.setValidFrom(campaignDto.getValidFrom());
        shop.setValidTill(campaignDto.getValidTill());
        shop.setCreatedAt(OffsetDateTime.now());
        shop.setSalesOrganisationId(campaignDto.getSalesOrganisationId());
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must declare an existing shop to update a campaign.");
    }

    Language language = languageRepository.getOne(campaignDto.getLanguageId());
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(language.getLanguageId()) && language.getLanguageId() != null) {
        language.setLanguageId(campaignDto.getLanguageId());
        shop.setLanguage(language);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must declare an existing language to update a campaign.");
    }

    campaign.setShop(shop);
    CampaignDto updatedCampaign = mapper.map(campaign);
    campaignRepository.saveAndFlush(campaign);

    return updatedCampaign;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I honestly do not care about updating the shop because I will never do that when updating a campaign

Why the `CascadeType.ALL`, then? You should never, **ever** use `CascadeType.ALL` with many-to-one associations. This is because `CascadeType.MERGE` rarely makes sense (you're essentially begging for unintended side effects like the one you describe), and `CascadeType.REMOVE` is just pure evil (by removing the child, you remove the parent, which in turn causes all its other children to be removed, since you've got another `CascadeType.ALL` on `Shop.campaigns`).

Also, if you never want to update the `Shop` while saving the `Campaign`, what is the purpose of the following code?

```
if (shop.getShopId() > 0 && shop.getShopId() != null) {
    shop.setCode(campaignDto.getShopCode());
    shop.setCurrency(campaignDto.getShopCurrency());
    shop.setCurrencyIsoCode(campaignDto.getShopCurrencyIso());
    shop.setValidFrom(campaignDto.getValidFrom());
    shop.setValidTill(campaignDto.getValidTill());
    shop.setCreatedAt(OffsetDateTime.now());
    shop.setSalesOrganisationId(campaignDto.getSalesOrganisationId());
}
```

If you truly do not want to update the `Shop`, just remove that part. As a side note, you might want to swap the conditions in the `if` clause.

Finally, if you're not seeing updates to the `CAMPAIGN` table, it might be because there are no actual changes to the `Campaign` entity. In general, Hibernate will retrieve the current state and compare it with the updated `Entity` to avoid unnecessary `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: First of all, drop the `CascadeType.ALL` from `Campaign.shop` and you'll stop seeing updates being made to the `SHOP` table. Secondly,  could you verify that `mapper.mapReverse(campaignDto)` does indeed return an instance of `Campaign` whose values differ from the ones already in the database?

Comment: Also, as I said, Hibernate must first retrieve the current state of `Campaign` as part of the merging process, so seeing a `SELECT` stament upon calling `campaignRepository.saveAndFlush(campaign)` is to be expected